# regular expression if doesn't else

Tags: if-statement

Why doesn't the regular expression in the following code ever else the codespli0 input string is dynamic in the regular application but when it changes the if statement doesn't else. why?

```
//first iteration input string
codespli0 = "var test = 0"

//second iteration input string
codespli0 = "test 2"


//process
var strTest = new RegExp("var");
alert(strTest);
if(strTest=="/var/"){
var test = strTest.exec(codespli0);
codepara0.innerHTML+=test+"<br />";
}else{
codepara0.innerHTML+="this"+"<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying your code should help here:

```
var strTest = "/var/"
if( strTest == "/var/" ){
    // Always runs this.
}else{
    // Never runs this.
}
```

You're setting the variable, then immediately testing to see if it's been set to that value.  I'm not even sure what you're aiming to do, but yes, that will ALWAYS be true.  Your if statement has nothing whatsoever to do with `codespli0`.

Comment: The question remain. Why doesn't the regular expression code else ?

Comment: I was assuming you mean, "Why doesn't the regular expression ever send the code into the else code fragment."  The answer:  Because the regular expression is not in the 'if'.  If this is not what you mean, then you need to re-phrase, because 'Why doesn't the regular expression code else" is not a coherent English sentence.

Answer (score 0):

In imperative programming (I'm assuming your code is JavaScript, since you haven't tagged the question with any specific language), an `if` statement is evaluated *once*, and **once only**, at the point when the program execution reaches it. Take this code for example:

```
if (something) {
    doSomething();
    something = false;
} else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

In this code, when the if statement is reached, the value of `something` will be checked to see if it is true (anything that isn't 0 in most languages). If it evaluates to true, `doSomething()` will be called. Otherwise, `doSomethingElse()` will be called.

Note that even though `something` is changed to `false` within the `if` statement, the `else` condition **will not be executed** because `something` was true **when the if statement was evaluated**.

If you want to run the same piece of code multiple times, you'll need to put it in a **function** and call the function, passing different arguments.

In your code, you'll probably want to do something like this:

```
function test (codespli0) {
    var strTest = new RegExp("var");
    var test = strTest.exec(codespli0);
    if (test) {
        codepara0.innerHTML += test + "<br />";
    } else {
        codepara0.innerHTML += "this" + "<br />";
    }
}

test("var test = 0");
test("test 2");
```

This way, you're actually running the code to test for a match **twice**, once for each value of `codespli0`, since the code is in a function and you're calling it for each value.

Comment: I have no problem giving mulitple strings to the function the question is why doesn't the if statement else when the string changes?

Comment: You're testing for the wrong condition. You're checking if the **regular expression** variable `strTest` is equal to `"var"`, which it always is, because the regular expression you use doesn't change. You need to test based on the result of executing the regular expression.

Comment: oops never mind case closed you all have valid points. It was my fault  I just didn't have the code structured poperly here is the working code.

Comment: var strTest = new RegExp("var");
var test = strTest.exec(codespli0);
alert(strTest);
if(test){
codepara0.innerHTML+=test+"<br />";
}else{
codepara0.innerHTML+="this"+"<br />";
}

Comment: If your problem is solved, mark one of the provided answers as accepted so it disappears from the unanswered questions list.